# Creating Unit files in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services

I have created this Unit file in `/lib/systemd/system/menu-core-prices-update.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description = core-price-update daemon
After network.target = auditd.service

[Service]
Type = forking
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh
ExecStop =  /usr/local/bin/stop-menu-core-prices-update.sh
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/reload-stop-menu-core-prices-update.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

From the command line I can run:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh
```

and the program starts properly. But if I start the daemon:

```
$ sudo systemctl start menu-core-prices-update.service
```

I get this error:

```
Jul 24 21:10:20 localhost systemd[13655]: menu-core-prices-update.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh: Exec format error
-- Subject: Process /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is 8.
Jul 24 21:10:20 localhost systemd[1]: menu-core-prices-update.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Jul 24 21:10:20 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start core-price-update daemon.
-- Subject: Unit menu-core-prices-update.service has failed
```

The permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 87 Jul 24 20:27 /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh
```

Comment: Recommended: use `/etc/systemd/system` instead of `/lib/systemd/system` for local unit files. See `man systemd.unit`

Comment: Does you script have a proper shebang line? Does the daemon have a PID file that systemd can use to keep track of the main process?

Comment: My suggestion removed after network.target and type from your systemd config and run it again.Beware some  command line can run not well on systemd. I tried to notify-send in shell script and run on systemd. It did not pop up any notification. Run it from terminal was ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue #1

I found this thread titled: [[Solved] Add custom script to systemd](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160766) which has the same error as your output shows above, mainly this bit:

> Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh: Exec format error

This error generally means that your script has one or more of these issues:

- Is not executable
- Is missing the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`)

To address these make sure that your script is executable:

```
$ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/start-menu-core-prices-update.sh
```

And be sure to add a shebang, `#!/bin/bash` to the top.

#### Issue #2

It looks like you have a typo on this line:

```
After network.target = auditd.service
```

This should likely be this:

```
After=network.target auditd.service
```

#### Issue #3

It's unclear to me why you're using the `Type = forking`. When you use this type you're `ExecStart=` is required to use a method that calls `fork()`. You're also suppose to be using the `PIDFile=` option.

I would expect your Java application would work fine with either `simple` or `oneshot`. See this U&L Q&A titled: [Forking in a systemd script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125714/forking-in-a-systemd-script) for more on this.